# Get Specific Json Array if an element is Matched

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON Array. If `device['name'] = 'DJ'`, then I want to retrieve the entire json array from *event_location* to *sum_text*, otherwise i do not want that array.

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "event_location": "San Jose",
      "event_type": "Party",
      "source_type": [
        "COMPANY",
        "CONSUM"
      ],
      "device": [
        {
          "name": "DJ",
          "date_order": "20210120",
          "manufacturer_country": "USA"
        }
      ],
      "problems": [
        "Material Rupture"
      ],
      "zip_code": "",
      "sum_text": [
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229361",
          "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
          "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
        },
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229362",
          "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
          "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "event_location": "New York",
      "event_type": "Baby Shower",
      "source_type": [
        "COMPANY",
        "CONSUM"
      ],
      "device": [
        {
          "name": "Musical Band",
          "date_order": "20210120",
          "manufacturer_country": "USA"
        }
      ],
      "problems": [
        "Material Rupture"
      ],
      "zip_code": "",
      "sum_text": [
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229361",
          "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
          "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
        },
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229362",
          "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
          "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "event_location": "Boston",
      "event_type": "Wedding",
      "source_type": [
        "COMPANY",
        "CONSUM"
      ],
      "device": [
        {
          "name": "Soft Music Band",
          "date_order": "20210120",
          "manufacturer_country": "USA"
        }
      ],
      "problems": [
        "Material Rupture"
      ],
      "zip_code": "",
      "sum_text": [
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229361",
          "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
          "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
        },
        {
          "sum_text_key": "220229362",
          "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
          "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I to iterate it so that I get only that particular array. Have tried to iterate it with for loop. But failing to retrieve the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
json = {...data here}

for event in json['results']:
    for device in event['device']:
        if device["name"] == "DJ":
            print(event)
```

In the line `print(event)` you can do whatever you want with the current event, append it to a list, return it, or whatever you require.

Also, note that device is a `list` and not a `dict`, so we iterate over all the devices to see if one of them matches the speficied name.

Comment: Thanks @Rudy did figure out the last print(event) statement. Was printing out device. Thanks a lot again